.NET Core Identity Framework Multiple Databases
I am using C# & ASP.NET Core Web API with Identity Framework.
Our project manger wishes to use multiple databases to create separation between client data.
The idea makes sense but when coming to .NET I don't think they ever thought about this.
I can't inherit Identity Framework class in two separate tables in two separate databases.
This forces me to rewrite the whole authentication process.
I am not that experienced in this environment and would like to know which option is the best or standard and if it be the multiple Databases approach,
How do I go about creating a multi tenancy?
I tried it but I can not create two or more separate Identities for the application.

Best is a single database... multi tenancy is well supported and much less complexity than multi-database.

This is my understanding as well. I know there are some benefits in using multiple databases. But it's not very developer friendly, or at least according to me it's not.

A daabase is only a variable, so you can switch between different Databases easily

Microsoft ASP.NET Core Identity framework

How do I switch between Databases when it needs to be defined in the Program.cs. once it's there it's there

So if you want to run your identity server, one per client, how would you identify which identity server to use when they login? That seems an odd way to do it IMO.

The idea was that we had main DB of sort and DBs for each user in the main DB. That is will allow me to use the Identity and subsequently be able to define the database name in the connection string. Is this the standard ways of doing things?
